# How does stream.write work?

Tags: c#, arrays, memorystream

Basically, why does this work?

```
System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
int a = 4;
byte[] barray = new byte[a];
stream.Write(barray, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(a));
```

When this doesn't:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
int a = 3;
byte[] barray = new byte[a];
stream.Write(barray, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(a));
```

This is the error I get:

```
The offset and length were greater than allowed for the matrix, or the number is greater than the number of elements from the index to the end of the source collection.
```

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf(a)` is 4 in both cases.

Comment: Wouldn't using `barray.Length` as your count be more sensible?

Comment: There is no difference in the posted code between two methods except 3 & 4.  Both should work.

Comment: He is doing Marshal.SizeOf(a), a is an int.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @jdweng There's certainly a difference and the second one doesn't work and it shouldn't, since `3 < 4`

Comment: It doesn't work because you're trying to extract 4 bytes from an array that's 3 bytes long. It's no more interesting than that. Using `Marshal.SizeOf` is seldom appropriate, unless you're actually marshalling data to unmanaged code. If you're using this in a hand-rolled binary serialization scheme, don't. `BinaryFormatter` and `protobuf` are among the existing wheels you're trying to reinvent.

Comment: @Default: quickly and subtly edited, thanks. :-)

Comment: I must be blind.  The first example is writing 3 bytes and second is writing 4 bytes.  I do not see any mixing of  3 and 4.

Comment: @jdweng: focus on [what the call is *reading* from](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stream.write). `barray` has 3 elements, `.SizeOf(a) == 4`. `Count > Length`.

Comment: The second example is creating an array of length 3, but then use `Marshal.SizeOf(a)` which returns a, which means he's trying to write 4 bytes from a 3 byte array to the stream. `Marshal.SizeOf(a)` doesn't care one way or the other about the *value* of that variable, it returns the size of it, which is 4 in both instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `Marshel.SizeOf(a)` you ask the size of the object in memory. Since `a` is an `int` the size is always 4.

When you say `byte[] barray = new byte[a];` you say:

Create an array called `barray` of type `byte` with length `a`. Thus in the first code block you create an array of length 4 and in the second one you create an array of length 3. Both array's contain only zero's.

Then you say: write the (empty) array to the stream, starting at position 0 and with length 4 (`Marshel.SizeOf(a)` is always 4 because `a` is an int).

The first example array has a length of 4 and thus works. The second example only contains 3 bytes and thus the length is not correct and you get an error.

---

If you wish to save the int to the stream as bytes explicitly you could call `BitConverter`:

```
System.IO.Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
int a = 4;
byte[] barray = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
stream.Write(barray, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(a));
```

Now you say: create an array called `barray` that is filled with the binary representation of integer variable `a`.

And then write that **filled** array to the stream.